# R sorting column

Tags: r

I have a file with several column loaded in R. What I want to achieve is to order the column of the file respect to the minimal value in each of the column. E.g.

Input(minA=0,minB=3,minC=1)
A B C
4 8 1
2 3 4
0 3 1

Output
A B C
4 1 8
2 4 3
0 1 3

Comment: You'd like to rearrange the columns *and* rename them? How would you like to deal with ties?

Comment: OK, then John has a great answer (the 2 corresponds to the `MARGIN` argument in `apply` - see `?apply` for more info)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try [`apply()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) this way:

```
mins <- apply(myData, 2, min)
o <- order(mins)
myData <- myData[,o]
```

Comment: look up the `apply` function in help... it's very clear for the MARGIN argument.  Just type `?apply`.